# Client Binding On RadGrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

i'm searching for a way to render a grid or do sth like need-datasource
event using xml client side data
I mean use the client side data to bind and render a grid
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

check out the demos under the Populating with data -> Client-side binding section of the RadGrid QSF.

Dick

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [client-side binding demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/databinding/defaultcs.aspx).